# remove 2 subviews in one go

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, subview

I am trying to remove two viewcontrollers (that have been added on top of each other) with one method. I have made the views in interfacebuilder. they all have their own .h and .m files to go with it.

**Scenario I am in:**

I have a main menu which has the view2 header file imported.
In a method I add the second view on top of the superview like so

```
view2ViewController * view2 = [[view2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"view2ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:view2.view];
```

then in view 2 I have added the view 3 header file so i can add view 3 as a subview ontop of view2. i have another method which is connected again to interface builder to a UIButton so upon button press a method gets called in view2 which adds view 3 on top in exactly the same way like so:

```
view3ViewController * view3 = [[view3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"view3ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:view3.view];
```

**What im trying to solve:**
I have a button in view 3 which should remove view 3.... and then it should also remove view 2 aswell so the main screen is visible.

How can this be achieved?

**What I have so far:**

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

This however only removes View 3... but leaves view 2 in place.

**What needs to be modified so that i can remove view 2 as well??**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is view3 a subview of view2 or the main screen view?

Comment: view 3 is a subview thats been added by view2

Comment: so the main view adds view two as a subview.. then view two adds view 3 as a subview.
Ive been working on this all day! and still am. IF you have any suggestions t will be helpful

Comment: so youre saying that if i use something like
[self.view removeFromSuperView] this only removes the view? and not its subviews (ie all the elements such as UIButton and so on that are contained within the view)???

Comment: No, it will not. It will just remove the view from its superview's `subviews` array. But if that makes the view's retain count to be 0, then the dealloc method should take care of releasing its subviews.

Comment: im confused. calling self.view removeFromSuperView will it remove just the view itself. or the view and all its subviews? thank you for your patience.

Comment: Just the view. But you're not responsible for releasing the contents removed view's `subviews` array (unless you took additional ownership), it's built-in dealloc method should take care of that. tl;dr: Just calling removeFromSuperview is fine. :)

Comment: ah ok. thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally do this as adding view2 and view3 as subviews of the main view. Then when the button actions are triggered, the adding and removing of subviews will be executed by the main view's view controller.

For a quick hack, I think you can try this in your button handler.

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

Though I'm not sure if you should be doing it. :P

Comment: this only removes the top view. which is great but i would also like to delete view2 which is below the top view (view3)

Comment: whats strange is that if  use the second line ...... view 2 and view 3 are no longer visible? are they still there though?

Comment: view2 is view3's superview, right? I thought it should work. Can't test for myself right now, I don't have a mac nearby. Anyway, I still recommend the first part of my answer better.

Comment: removeFromSuperview will remove them from their superview's `subviews` array. If you are retaining them elsewhere, they will still be there (in memory, I mean).

Comment: im actually trying to remove completely view 2 and view 3... upon button press in view 3.

Comment: Then that should remove them completely (assuming that you did release view2 and view3 after their respective `addSubview:` calls).

Comment: thats something i did not add..... ok so ive added that... so is this line [self.view.superview removeFromSuperview]; allowed? you mentioned it was a quick hack.... at the moment both view 3 and view 2 disappear i should be overjoyed but feel as if its not the right way to get rid of the two views?

Comment: Well, it is making a child view tell it's parent view to destroy itself. Not the usual flow of things, but technically it does work. At most, it may not be a good practice to do it that way.

Comment: The last thing i want is for the application to be rejected by apple. And for them to tell me that this is not the appropriate way of getting rid of a parent view and its child view. lol :P Is there any other way of being able to delete it since you also feel that it may not be good practice to do it the way suggested?

Comment: Yeah, see the first paragraph of my answer: make view2 and view3 subviews of the main view, and make the buttons that add and remove view2 and view3 call methods in the main view's view controller. That way, adding and removing of subviews are done by the main view controller, which I feel is a better flow.

Comment: oh right i see. so basically: add all the header files for the individual views to the main view. then have the method: 'show view2' and 'show view3' in the main view. I tried to do this before in another project, and the problem i was having with that was how to connect the button from view2 to the main view Showview3 method?

Comment: In the same way, you can try using something like `[self.view.superview removeView2AndView3];` in the button's action. -removeView2AndView3 will be in your main view controller, and it will do the removing of views.

Comment: ok, i can see what you are doing. So is this the way to call a method in your parent view?

Comment: Yup, that's what the superview property is for. :)

Comment: lol at the moment im getting something like 'UIView' may not respond to '-removeView2AndView3' which is weird as ive imported the parent views header file to the current view; or am i misunderstanding the error warning?

Comment: You must cast it to your main view controllers subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
    [[[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: hi thank you for helping out. i need something that will delete the view below my current view

Comment: i am so stuck at this. Ive been trying to remove my second view from the view i am in for a while. Maybe i can specify which view to delete? by saying something like remove SecondViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but I get the impression that pushing a new view controller is what you want. If you have a UINavigationController in your app, you'd just have to do a

`[navigationController pushViewController:view2 aimated:YES]`

To go back to the main menu when the button is pressed, you should define a delegate protocol that looks something like this::

```
@protocol View3ViewControllerDelegate
- (void)view3ControllerBackToMainMenuButtonPressed:(View3ViewController*)controller;
@end
```

This protocol is then implemented by the class that actually pushes the other view controllers. In the implementation, you'd pop all view controllers you don't want to be displayed anymore. To do this, you could use

`[navigationController popToViewController:myMainMenuViewController animated:YES]`

or if your main menu view controller is actually the root  view controller:

`[navigationController [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

That way only one class is responsible for pushing and popping all view controllers and handling that "Back to Main Menu" button. Using a custom protocol as described above is the recommended way to handle the popping of pushed view controllers in a scenario like this.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This sounds like a proper way to handle views in this kind of situation. The only thing is that i am not using a navigation controller. Could you shed light onto what may be the best option for me?! I simply have the mainview which addssubview :view2... upon button press in the mainview. Then i have a button in view 2 that addssubview:view3. inside view3 i have another button which addsubview:4 . Now in view 4 i would like to get rid of view 4 and view 3 by clicking the button in view 4. at the moment im doing it like this: [self.view.superview removeFromSuperView];

Comment: that is called in view 4 in the button action. which with the help of atlealice i have understood that this will remove view4's parent view view3 removing view 4 as well...... the only thing is.... is this the way to go? or can i implement something what youve suggested to make it more acceptable? thank you for your patience.

Comment: This is more or less the same thing as my suggestion, just that this one utilizes a navigation controller. I was assuming you are just adding subviews because you can't/didn't want to use a navigation controller. Nonetheless, the approach is the same: from the child view, call a method on the parent view that will pop it from the navigation controller. I suggest you evaluate if you actually need to use a navigation controller instead, then decide which one to use. :)

Comment: Is there a good reason why you don't use an UINavigationController? After all, you're navigating around different views loaded from a bunch of XIBs managed by view controllers. Handling that is the reason that the UINavigationController class exists. But if you really can't use one, I guess the approach of simply adding the views as subviews is one possible way to go. Just remember to also properly retain and release not only the views, but also the view controllers - thus implementing your own version of a UINavigationController : )